# Given an LLVM IR, can we generate Clang AST?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-ir

This question is purely from research point of view and right now I am not looking at any practical aspect of it.

Just like we have decompilers which can take in a binary code and generate LLVM IR, like
https://github.com/repzret/dagger or https://github.com/avast/retdec
 and many other.
Do we have some code generator which can convert an LLVM IR to Clang AST?

Thank You in advance.

---

Found one dropped project -
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2OTg

Looking for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the AST to the LLVM IR is a one way street.

Take a look at this picture.
[image: LLVM Toolchain]

A source code file of the high level programming language (which maybe C, C++, or Rust), is converted into the Clang AST. This is a data structure which has a knowledge about the source code constructs of the programming language itself. An AST is specific to a programming language. It is a description of the parsed source code file of the programming language, in the same way as the Javascript DOM tree is a description of the HTML document. This means that the AST contains information specific to that programming language. If the programming language is Rust, the Rust AST might for example contain functional coding constructs.

The LLVM IR however is sometimes described as a portable, high-level assembly language, because it has constructions that can map closely to system hardware.

A frontend module converts a high level programming language into LLVM IR. It does this by generating a language specific AST and then recursively traversing that AST and generating LLVM code constructs representing each node in the AST. Then we have LLVM IR code. Then the backend module converts the LLVM IR into an architecture specific assembly code.

[image: LLVM]

There are multiple frontend modules, one for each high level language that you want to convert into LLVM IR. Once this conversion is complete, the generated LLVM IR has no way of knowing what programming language it came from. You could take C++ code and the same code written in Rust, and after generating the LLVM IR you won't be able to tell them apart.

Once the LLVM IR has been generated any high level language specific information is gone. This is including information about how to generate an AST, because an AST needs knowledge about coding constructs specific to that programming language.

Going from a high level (more abstract) source code representation into a medium level, such as LLVM IR, and even into a lower level, such as assembly code is *relatively easy*.

Going the other way, from a very low level machine specific code, to a more abstract source code of a high level programming language is much harder. This is because in high level programming languages you can solve the same problem many different ways, while the representation of code in assembly language is more limited, so you have no way of knowing which specific high level coding construct the low level code originally came from.

This is why in principle you cannot go from the LLVM IR into an AST. If someone would indeed try to do such a thing, it won't be an exact same representation of the original high level language source code, and it won't be very readable.

Comment: that would be a kind of LLVM reverse engineering